# How to get application root path in Symfony 4 Console Command

Tags: php, symfony, console, symfony4

I have a simple **Symfony 4** Console application. 
In `execute()` method i need to print application root path.

This `$this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getRootDir()` - don't work.
This `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();` - don't work.
This `$this->get('parameter_bag')->get('kernel.project_dir');` - don't work.

How can i get application root path?

Comment: what about passing it explicitly to the console command using https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service

Comment: `$this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest not injecting container to the command but passing the param explicitly in service definition

**src/Command**

```
class YourCommand extends Command
{
    private $path; 

    public function __construct(string $path) 
    {
         $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
       echo $this->path;
    }
}
```

**config/services.yaml**

```
services:
    # ...

    App\Command\YourCommand:
        arguments:
            $path: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Comment: why you suggest not injecting container to the symfony command?

Comment: 1. The code is more readable, by looking at the dependencies you +- what the class do
2. The class is testable, you can mock the dependencies instead of mokcing whole container
3. Injecting Container is considered as bad practice 
4. You'll be notifed about missing dependencies when container is complied. 
5. Easier type hinting when you do $container->get('mailer') IDE has no idea what it is unless you use `@var Mailer` etc. 

There are a lot more "for" using direct dependencies

Comment: `You probably forgot to call the parent constructor.`